# react fullpage js how to use silentMoveTo function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullpage.js

I want to use fullpage silentMoveTo function in react fullpage but it requires an anchor link to use the function, I can use moveTo function without an anchor link, is there any way to use the function without anchorlink or with a useful way for react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as detailed in [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage):

```
<button onClick={() => fullpageApi.silentMoveTo(2,1)}>
    Move down
</button>
```

You can replace the button in here to test it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/m34yq5q0qx